# Change the Default Download Location of file

Tags: web, browser

In my application, I have a link from which a PDF file can be downloaded on click.

Here is my Code:

**LINK**

```
<s:submit name="download" value="download" action="generateCoverSheet">
```

**CONFIG FILE**

```
<action name="generateCoverSheet" method="generateCoverSheet"
    class="probityfinancials.bills.action.BillsAction">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
            <param name="contentType">${documentContentType}</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

And In my action class I have provided dynamic filename using `fileName` variable and inputStrem using `fileInputStream`.

And on clicking on the link my file is by default the generated file is downloaded to the **Downloads** folder of my system. My doubt is Can I change the location, where my file is being downloaded..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sry @RomanC Now I have made the changes

Comment: You cannot. It is not related to S2 or any other framework.

Comment: @JayaramJai Are you seriously what to get an answer to this question? Check your browser settings where files are downloaded by default.